# How to combine two Gatsby sites together

Tags: gatsby

Currently, I have two sites developed using gatsby.js deployed to example.com and blog.example.com. I want to create a subdirectory of blog.example.com to example.com/blog.

Is there any way to do it without merging both the repository?

Comment: I use `lerna` to manage multiple gatsby sites and merge them together. Even though you might need to work on a single repo, but both sites will still be isolated from each other, they'll work as independent packages. This link might help: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-01-01-publish-multiple-gatsby-sites/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a path prefix on your Gatsby blog site to put everything on /blog

See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/

Basically, add the path prefix to `gatsby-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: `/blog`,
}
```

Then add `--prefix-paths` to all your scripts:

```
"build": "gatsby build --prefix-paths",
"serve": "gatsby serve --prefix-paths",
```

Now that your Gatsby main site is at `/` and your Gatsby blog site is prefixed with `/blog`, the question is how to deploy these two separate sites on to one host. You could create a deploy script that does the following:

- Build Gatsby main site
- Build Gatsby blog site (with `--prefix-paths`)
- Copy contents of `/public` from Gatsby blog to `/public/blog` in Gatsby main
- Deploy to hosting from Gatsby main

Keep in mind that what you will have created is two separate Gatsby sites on the same host, so some things may not work the way you want. For example, I don't think you'll be able to pre-fetch pages using `<Link>` when navigating between the two sites. So you'll have to evaluate your own pros/cons between having separate sites vs. combining the sites into a single Gatsby site.

Hope this helps!